# My town house was flooded from my ceiling opening up leaking water, is it the poor caulking we used more than 5 years back?

Tags: bathroom, water, caulking

I have a 1964 townhouse I reside in I love it; however, 3 years ago I felt drops in my kitchen shrugged, I'll see about that later rushing off to work.

Then 2 years ago, a bubble began to form in the corner ceiling. While using the restroom I looked down and really paid attention to the caulking coming up from around the tub and the toilet it looks moldy and torn up. I called to have someone come for a consultation to check it out.

He came scheduled me and then returned to fix the ceiling never the problem and it is leaking again this time forming a shape of a bloated person between the walls.

Comment: HI! Welcome! I'm not entirely sure what you're asking...Could it be leaking because of bad caulking?  Sure. Is it likely that there are more serious problems going on?  You bet. And three or more years of leaking are likely to have caused all kinds of issues....We'll need more information to help you out and a few pictures is always a good idea. The "bloated person" between the walls sounds kind of problematic too....

Comment: So there's a restroom above? If so, you have a leak, and it's unlikely that it's just caulking. Get a good general contractor to take your ceiling down and figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a bathroom above the location, then you have a plumbing leak you should fix post-haste.

If you do not have a bathroom there, you might have a leaky pipe but it's vastly more likely that it's time to fix your roof.

**You must stop water ingress into the home.  It will destroy your home in short order**.